# Chrome not hiding data element on jQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to hide a group of elements with attribute `data-fineBin = "UNCLASSIFIED"` on a click event.  It works fine in IE and FF but doesn't want to work on Chrome.  Any idea what might be missing?  Note that hidden is a global variable that is initialized as false on page load.

```
$(document).on('click', '#toggle', function (event) {
    if(!hidden) {
        $('[data-fineBin="UNCLASSIFIED"]').hide();
        hidden = true;
    } else {
        $('[data-fineBin="UNCLASSIFIED"]').show();
        hidden = false;
    }
})
```

The data elements are generated using d3.js (see below for partial).  I'm not sure if this helps.

```
var circle = waferBox.selectAll("circle")
    .data(function(data) {return data.detailWafer;})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        var x = jsonScaleUp * makeNumber(d.x);
        return xScale(x);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        var y = jsonScaleUp * makeNumber(d.y);
        return yScale(y);
    })
    .attr("r",3)
    .style("fill",function(d) {return d.color;})
    .attr("data-fineBin",function(d){
        if(d.fineBin) {
            return d.fineBin
        } else {
            return "null"
        }});
```

Comment: No info on chrome's console?

Comment: works here http://jsfiddle.net/sC2fw/ checked in chrome and ff on mac

Comment: Does the click get called? Do the selectors find elements? is the variable what you expect?

Comment: fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bBL8j/ no ouput in chrome console

Comment: @andrew, you have a stray [ breaking your example.

Comment: @JohnBoker Oh yes :) that works in chrome without the [ http://jsfiddle.net/bBL8j/2/

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fiddle it myself and got an undefined error on hidden.
Anyway, I'd suggest the next approach:

```
$('#toggle').click( function(){
$('[data-fineBin="UNCLASSIFIED"]').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Hige.  I tried your recommendation and it worked with IE and FF but again still isn't working with Chrome.  In the version that I posted I check to make sure that the variable hidden was being toggled and it was, it just isn't hiding the elements.  I had someone who could access the site (it's on an intranet) try with Chrome and they saw the same issue.

Comment: Version of chrome? I'm using chrome on Win7 and works for me :S

Answer (score 0):

I tried quite a few options still couldn't get it to work in Chrome so I tried to use the same toggle button to turn of a group of elements by their class name and it worked on all platforms.  So, I changed my d3.js so that UNCLASSIFIED was assigned as the class and then toggled those elements.  In this case there 100's of elements that are being toggled, I'm not sure if that played into it or not.

```
 $('#toggle').click( function(){
    $('.UNCLASSIFIED').toggle();
});
```